# Mounted hard drive is not showing any files

Tags: hard-disk

I've mounted the my hard-drive (first run lsblock to identify it). It mounts but does not show any files.

I've mounted in someone else's windows machine and all files are showing right away.

To mount it manually I run:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/me/
```

How to troubleshoot this?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

**Edit**

```
$ df /dev/sdb1 -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb1       932G  119G  813G  13% /media/me
```

And also

```
$ mount | grep sdb
/dev/sdb1 on /media/me type fuseblk (rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
```

And from the `journalctl`

```
Jan 12 16:10:37 code kernel: scsi host1: usb-storage 3-2:1.0
Jan 12 16:10:38 code kernel: scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  External USB 3.0 0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Jan 12 16:10:38 code kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
Jan 12 16:10:41 code kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
Jan 12 16:10:41 code kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Jan 12 16:10:41 code kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
Jan 12 16:10:41 code kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or>
Jan 12 16:10:41 code kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

### Update

Files reappeared after a while of the HD being connected via USB.

Comment: What does `df /dev/sdb1` return? Maybe it is empty after all?

Comment: said files are shown when opening on windows OS @FelixJN, but included result in post

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show `mount | grep sdb`

Comment: Look at `sudo journalctl  -b 0 /dev/sdb`. The disk could have been left in an unworkable state by Windows.

Comment: It would help if you told us what the file system type is, version of Windows and where was it created. The assumption is that it is NTFS. And post the output of `ls -la /media/me`. Re-dit your question...

Comment: @waltinator done. I know how to edit XD

Comment: @Bib now all the files re appeared, it seems that the reading took years, for some weird reason